# Highlight keywords in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, highlight

I have this sentense, "The man went outside".

I also have 4 search criterias I would like to get highligted (ignore the brackets), [went|"an WeNT o"|a|t] with [span id="something"][/span].

I have tried out a lot of stuff but I can't figure out how to do this in classic ASP!? If I insert a  somewhere in the text, it will search the HTML code for SPAN too, which is bad or it will not find the text as it has been messed up with HTML code. I also tried inserting on all positions in the original text and even with some magic regular expression which I do not understand but I can't get this working :-/

The search-thing is divided with | and can be anything from 1 to 20 things to search for.

Can anyone help me solving how to do this?

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found and tweaked some code and it works perfectly for me:

```
Function highlightStr (haystack, needles)

' Taken (and tweaked) from these two sites:
' http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/asp-highlight-keywords-295641.html
' http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/scriptingVisualBasicscript/Jul2005/post23377133.asp
'    
' INPUT: haystack = search in this string
' INPUT: needles = searches divided by |... example: this|"is a"|search
' OUTPUT: HTML formatted highlighted string
'
If Len(haystack) > 0 Then

  ' Delete the first and the last array separator "|" (if any)
  If Left(needles,1) = "|" Then needles = Right(needles,Len(needles)-1)
  If Right(needles,1) = "|" Then needles = Mid(needles,1,Len(needles)-1)

  ' Delete a multiple seperator (if any)
  needles = Replace(needles,"||","|")

  ' Delete the exact-search chars (if any)
  needles = Replace(needles,"""","")

  ' Escape all special regular expression chars
  needles = Replace(needles,"(","\(")
  needles = Replace(needles,")","\)")
  needles = Replace(needles,".","\.")

  If Len(needles) > 0 Then
    haystack = " " & haystack & " "
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "(" & needles & ")"
    re.IgnoreCase = True 
    re.Global = True 
    highlightStr = re.Replace(haystack,"<span style='background-color:khaki;'>$&</span>")
  Else
    highlightStr = haystack
  End If

Else
  highlightStr = haystack
End If

End Function
```